# Getting strange error in PHP script running on unix

Tags: php

I'm running a php in a unix shell and I'm getting the following error.
The script is a web scraper and it work fine on my host if I access it. But I want to run it as a cron job, What shoul I do?

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.lomamatkat.fi/iframes/last-minute-offers/?lastminute_next=50): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /var/www/customers/lentovertailufi/public_html/matkat/script/lomamatkat.php on line 30
>   PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /var/www/customers/lentovertailufi/public_html/matkat/script/lomamatkat.php on line 30

Comment: `URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration` is the key

Comment: you should read the error message :/

Comment: did you actually read the error message??

Answer (score 7):

Update your php.ini file, and set the 'allow_url_fopen' option to 'On'.

Comment: but why does it work when I access it like localhost/script.php on my apache server

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to change allow_url_fopen consider using use curl (if must be php) or Wget

Answer (score 0):

go to the php.ini and enable that or use curl or one of the other http get functions. file_get_contents is considered a dangerous system call for urls because people can slip files into it as well.